# Sending object with BufferedImage through socket. Not serializable exception

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I'm trying to make a client server program that allows users to upload pictures for their profile. As a result I have a JFileChooser that get's a path makes a BufferedImage and a UserId and makes Object out of it. I'm trying to send this object from my client to my server but I'm getting NotSerializableException.

Here's the class for the object.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserPicture implements Serializable
{
    BufferedImage profilePic;
    int userId;

    public UserPicture(BufferedImage profilePic, int userId)
    {
        this.profilePic=profilePic;
        this.userId=userId;
    }

    public BufferedImage getProfilePic()
    {
        return profilePic;
    }

    public int getUserID()
    {
        return userId;
    }
}
```

I'm sending it through the socket like this:

```
objOutStream.writeObject(theObject);//this is the line throwing the exception
objOutStream.flush();
```

Now I'm aware that BufferedImages can be sent with something like `ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);`
but I'm not entirely sure how to send it within an object.

**Edit: the solution below fixed my exception problem but now on the server side the BufferedImage is null... Is this a result of the solution?**